# how to use Images without path in handlebars

Tags: java, spring, handlebars.js

I want to deliver image list into Handlebars view.

```
ArrayList<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>();
for(Photos p : photos){
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(p.getImage());
    BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(bis);
    images.add(new ImageIcon(bim));
}

model.addAttribute("photos", images);
```

I'm sure that there are ImageIcon objects in this arrayList by debugging.
Then, how can I use this array in handlebars like this.

```
{{#each photos as |photo|}}
    <img src={{photo}}>
{{/each}}
```

I want to use this images without file path.

Comment: The type of p.getImage() is byte[] which is from postgresql

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/displayImage")
public void displayImage(@RequestParam("email")String email, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<Photos> list = photoService.showImages(email);

    byte[] binaryImage = list.get(0).getImage();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
    response.getOutputStream().write(binaryImage);
    response.getOutputStream().close();
}

<img src="/displayImage/?email={{userInfo.email}}"/>
```